# MySQL server inactive state?how to make it active? error --> mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

When I execute `sudo service mysql status` and `mysql` it shows the following error,
I used all the solutions that give in the StackOverflow but I can not overcome that problem. I use Ubuntu 18.04LTS

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please check system_logs file, else run this command `journalctl -xe`. then you will get more information about this error.

Comment: i check journalctl -xe  and made some changes but still show me error that is  ` Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2 "No such file or directory")`

Comment: Please check your MySQL path is correct or not? might be you installed in under some other folder. please check `mysqld.sock` location and make sure that is correct.